# Python - How get all replies of particular tweet with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I read some questions but I could not find my problem!

I use the following code to get the replies,

```
import csv
import tweepy
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

# Oauth keys
consumer_key = "XXX"
consumer_secret = "XXX"
access_token = "XXX"
access_token_secret = "XXX"

# Authentication with Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# update these for the tweet you want to process replies to 'name' = the account username and you can find the tweet id within the tweet URL
name = 'amir'
tweet_id = '1270923526690664448'

replies=[]
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,q='to:'+name, result_type='recent', timeout=999999).items():
    if hasattr(tweet, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
        if (tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str==tweet_id):
            replies.append(tweet)

with open('replies_clean.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=('user', 'text'))
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for tweet in replies:
        row = {'user': tweet.user.screen_name, 'text': tweet.text.replace('\n', ' ')}
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

but unfortunately it does not receive the complete one, and for example, from 2000 relpies, sometimes get 20  sometimes 2 and sometimes nothing!
What could be the problem?

Comment: All 2000 replies have `'in_reply_to_status_id_str'` as an attribute?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I dont want scrap special tweet, I used this code for random tweet of some account and I have this problem for every tweet I used it!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Your current code is retrieving all replies to a specific user `amir` and checking in the loop if that reply is associated(replying) to a specific tweet (`in_reply_to_status_id_str`). The reason why you are getting different  tweets is that the flag `recent` gets only latest replies to the `user` variable and that can change in a period of time.

In order to retrieve directly the replies with tweepy you can use this code:

````
    import tweepy
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='your_bearer_token_here')
    replies = []

    tweet_id = '1622703016670384128'
    query = 'in_reply_to_tweet_id:'+tweet_id
    # all fields you need from a Tweet
    tweet_fields = ['id', 'text', 'created_at']

    for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=query, tweet_fields=tweet_fields).flatten(limit=40):
        print(tweet.data)
```**strong text**
````